# Count does not behave properly with null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the number of projects assigned to each employee. But I also want to include the name of those who are not currently working on any project, obviously the count value should be either blank or null for those. Here is what I have done so far:

```
Select
lname
, ssn
, COUNT(*) AS projectnum
FROM
employee LEFT OUTER JOIN works_on
ON essn=ssn
GROUP BY 
lname
ORDER BY
projectnum DESC
```

It works just fine except, in projectnum field, it puts 1 for those who are not working on any project, rather than null, how can I fix that?

Comment: you're missing the `ssn` in the group by

Comment: I added it to GROUP BY, still same behavior!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're counting the wrong thing. Saying `count(*)` essentially counts the rows returned, you're getting rows with NULL projects (as intended) but `count(*)` sees those as rows so you get `1`. You need to count a column that will be NULL if there is no project and non-NULL if there is:

```
select ..., count(c) as projectnum ....
```

where `c` is some non-NULL column from `works_on`.

---

For example, I have these tables in my MySQL sandbox:

```
mysql> select * from posts;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+

mysql> select * from posts_tags;
+---------+--------+
| post_id | tag_id |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |      1 |
|       1 |      2 |
|       1 |      3 |
|       2 |      2 |
|       2 |      3 |
|       3 |      2 |
+---------+--------+
```

You can see the difference between `count(*)` and `count(tag_id)`:

```
mysql> select posts.id, count(*) from posts left join posts_tags on posts.id = posts_tags.post_id group by posts.id;
+------+----------+
| id   | count(*) |
+------+----------+
|    1 |        3 |
|    2 |        2 |
|    3 |        1 |
|    4 |        1 |
+------+----------+

mysql> select posts.id, count(tag_id) from posts left join posts_tags on posts.id = posts_tags.post_id group by posts.id;
+------+---------------+
| id   | count(tag_id) |
+------+---------------+
|    1 |             3 |
|    2 |             2 |
|    3 |             1 |
|    4 |             0 |
+------+---------------+
```

Doing a `count(*)` in the first one gives you a stray `1` for `id=4` but `count(tag_id)` in the second gives you the expected `0`.

Comment: You are right, I changed it to count(pno) and now projectnum is changed to 0 for that employee. Thanks.